# $33$ students in clubs

Tags: combinatorics, estimation

> There are $33$ students. Several clubs are set up among them each one about either math or physics. Clubs with a single member are allowed.
>
> For each $i\in[1,11]$ there exists at least one club with $i$ members, and each student is in exactly one math club and one physics club.
>
> Show that there exists two students who share the same club in both subjects.

For the students in the same club we connect a line between them. So each club with $m$ members has correspondence with $\mbox C_m^2$ lines.

However if we use this kind of estimation we get there’re at least $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{11}\mbox C_m^2<\mbox C_{33}^2 $ lines so it doesn’t work.

Now I guess this is because in the estimation only $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{11}=33$ students are considered whereas the sum of members of all clubs($66$) is twice as much so lines get wasted a lot.

Can anyone improve the strategy?

Comment: 33 students total with some in math, some in physics, and some in both? Also, what does `According to statistics` mean here? Is that additional information, or is the question saying that is necessarily true (which it doesn't appear to be)

Comment: Your sum from $1$ to $11$ should come out as $66$.  Hint: since the clubs are precisely defined by the rules (no slack for extra clubs to exist), the information about whether the clubs are maths or physics is irrelevant - if you find two students in the same pair of clubs, one must be maths and the other physics. How many clubs are there?

Comment: Please explain why the following scenario isn't a counter-example: Each maths class contains exactly one person; each physics class contains one person, and each person is a member of one physics class and one maths class. I feel like the sentence, "It was found that there exists at least one club with i members, i∈[1,11] and each student is in exactly one math club and one physics club" is unclear.

Comment: @AdamRubinson In your example there’s no club with $2,3,\ldots$ students.

Comment: Ok, so I think the sentence, "It was found that there exists at least one club with $i$ members, $i\in[1,11]$ and each student is in exactly one math club and one physics club." is better written as, "For each $i\in[1,11]$ there exists at least one club with $i$ members, and each student is in exactly one math club and one physics club."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of total memberships is: $1+2+3+\cdots + 11 = 66$, and each student is in exactly two clubs, so there are exactly $11$ clubs for $33$ students.

If $M$ is the number of maths clubs, then $11-M$ is the number of physics clubs.

The number of distinct pairs of one maths club and one physics club is $M(11-M)$, and

$$M(11-M) \le 5.5^2 = 30.25<33$$

So by pigeonhole, at least two students among the $33$ share the same clubs in both subjects.

Answer (score 0):

You did a silly and thought $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{11} k=33$ but actually $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{11} k=66.$ So now try the problem for yourself again and see if you get it before reading my solution below.

Since for all $i\in [1,11]$, there exists at least one club with $i$ members, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{11}k =66 = 33\times 2:$ Therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{11}k $ describes *all* of the clubs: there are exactly $11$ clubs: one with one member, one with two members, ..., one with ten members, one with eleven members.

Each of the people in the $11-$ member club (assume it's a Physics club) belong to another club- for each person their other club must be a maths club. So we have $11$ people in at most $10$ maths clubs: so by PHP at least two of them must be in the same maths club and we are done.